# Switching to browser from a native android app with Appium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webview, appium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to handle the opening browser from a native app.

I have a native android app. When I click a link on it, it opens a browser. I'm trying to switch to that browser but couldn't do it. My code block is:

```
Set<String> contextNames = ((AppiumDriver) webDriver).getContextHandles();
    for (String contextName : contextNames) {
        if (contextName.contains("android.browser")) {
            ((AppiumDriver) webDriver).context(contextName);
        }
    }
```

After I debugged some (for further questions)
My app contains a vebview on all pages. Here's what I get when I check with getContextHandles() on any page:

```
0 = "NATIVE_APP"
1 = "WEBVIEW_com.dmall.app"
```

If I switch context to webview and getPageSource(), I see there is an empty view.
    html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">head>/head>body>iframe name="chromedriver dummy frame" src="about:blank">/iframe>/body>

(I removed some chars because of this page accept html)

I started the test again and after click the link that opens a browser and check getContextHandles(), I see

```
0 = "NATIVE_APP"
1 = "WEBVIEW_com.dmall.app"
2 = "WEBVIEW_com.android.browser"
```

Everything looks as it should be, right?

Then I'm doing:
     ((AppiumDriver) webDriver).context(WEBVIEW_com.android.browser);

when I check the page source, I see the same empty webview
html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

By the way, I can't switch to other webview after this point, it says:
"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: We already have a chromedriver instance running (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 134 milliseconds"
I guess this is normal

So, how can I switch to browser, any idea, solution, questions, brain storming, anything can be useful.

My capabilities is here:

```
    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.android();
    capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "http://172.20.0.196:8088/android/mfandroid-debug.apk");
    capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "AndroidEmulator" + RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(3));
    capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Android");
    capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "5.1");
    capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 3000);
    capability.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", "true");
    capability.setCapability("sendKeyStrategy", "setValue");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue before so I think I am the right person to answer this question.

**You can switch to webView of the app under test [AUT] only and not to the webView of any other app**. Which means your app under test is **app1** and you want to switch to webView of **app2**.

To switch to webView of app2 you need to change the app Capabilites at run time after you perform some actions on **app1**. I suggest you to do:

1. Close the driver once you click on the link in your first native app (I hope after clicking the link will be opened in the app2).
2. Re-initialise the driver with new app capabilities of app2.
3. Now, you should able to switch to webView of app2 (browser).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try this on monday.